# How can I pass multiple data with GetServerSideProps

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I'm trying to pass multiple sanity data into a component. but I can only use getserversideprops one time. how can I use more than one sanity data?

pages > members.tsx

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({props}: any) => {

//HERE I NEED TO QUERY 4 MORE DATA // 
  const query = `*[ _type == "teammembers"] {
        _id,
        name,
        position,
        bordercolor,
        memberimage,
    }`;
 const members = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
 return { props: { members } };
};

const teammembers = ({ members }: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TeamMembersComponent members={members} />
    </>
  );
};
```

components > members.tsx

```js
const TeamMembersComponent = ({ members }: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MembersContainer members={members} />
    </>
  );
};
```

other data that I need to use. for example

```js
 const query = `*[_type == "projectschema" && slug.current == $id][0] {
     _id,
        title,
         categories[0] -> {
                  title,
          },
         date,
         website,
        thumbnail,
         client,
         company,
       description,
    }`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query to something like:

```
const query = `{
  'teamMembers': *[ _type == "teammembers"] {
    _id,
    name,
    position,
    bordercolor,
    memberimage,
  },
  'otherStuff': *[ _type != "teammembers"] {...}
}`;
```

Notice the queries are wrapped in `{}` and are each named (which is how you can access them).